# Spatial neighbors in ggplot2

Tags: r, sf, sp, ggplot2, spdep

I'm trying to make a space plot with `ggplot()` as indicated [here](https://mbjoseph.github.io/posts/2018-12-27-plotting-spatial-neighbors-in-ggplot2/), but I'm having trouble using the `nb2lines()` function.

.shp files are [here](https://mega.nz/file/0ppCHKjS#Uq871u3vJoO9_tFFItZny1LGZ1zwXe-lDLWFzBd0-LI)

```
Error in if (!is.na(projargs) && !nzchar(projargs)) projargs <- NA_character_ : missing value where TRUE/FALSE is required
```

while using plot() if it works for me, how could I fix it?

```
ec = st_read("nxparroquias.shp") %>% 
  sf::st_transform('+init=epsg:4326')

peta_nb <- poly2nb(ec)
plot(ec, col="white", border="grey")
plot(peta_nb, coordinates(as_Spatial(ec.sp2)), col="red", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

**What I got**

```
nc_sp2 <- as(ec, 'Spatial')
neighbors <- poly2nb(nc_sp)
neighbors_sf <- as(nb2lines(neighbors, coords = coordinates(nc_sp2)), 'sf')
neighbors_sf <- st_set_crs(neighbors_sf, st_crs(ec))

nc_sp <- as(ec, 'Spatial') 
neighbors <- poly2nb(nc_sp)
neighbors_sf <- as(nb2lines(neighbors, coords = coordinates(nc_sp2)), 'sf')

#Error in if (!is.na(projargs) && !nzchar(projargs)) projargs <- NA_character_ : missing value where TRUE/FALSE is required

#neighbors_sf <- st_set_crs(neighbors_sf, st_crs(ec))

#ggplot(nc_sp) + 
#  geom_sf(fill = 'salmon', color = 'white') +
#  geom_sf(data = neighbors_sf) +
#  theme_minimal() +
#  ylab("Latitude") +
#  xlab("Longitude")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `sp` and `sf`objects, in your code, `nc_sp`is a `sp`object and you are trying to use `geom_sf` to plot it, which is a method for `sf` objects; this code works on my computer:

```
library(sf)
library(spdep)
library(ggplot2)

ec = st_read("nxparroquias.shp") %>% 
  sf::st_transform(4326) # function accepts the EPSG code number

nc_sp <- as(ec, 'Spatial') # coords argument uses sp style
neighbors <- poly2nb(nc_sp) 

neighbors_sf <- as(nb2lines(neighbors, coords = coordinates(nc_sp),
                        proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")), 'sf')

    
ggplot(ec) + # the sf object
    geom_sf(fill = 'salmon', color = 'white') +
    geom_sf(data = neighbors_sf) +
    theme_minimal() +
    ylab("Latitude") +
    xlab("Longitude")
```

[image]

Comment: I still have the same error `Error in if (!is.na(projargs) && !nzchar(projargs))...` with the function 'nb2lines'. The version I have of `spdep` is `0.4.4`.

Comment: I'm using spdep version 1.1, did you try to update the package?

Comment: I just updated `sf ` version `0.7.7` and `spdep` `1.1.5` and I still get the error :/

Comment: so is it here you get the error? `nb2lines(neighbors, coords = coordinates(nc_sp))`

Comment: yes, `Error in if (!is.na(projargs) && !nzchar(projargs)) projargs <- NA_character_ : missing value where TRUE/FALSE is required`

Comment: neighbors_sf = as(nb2lines(neighbors, coords = coordinates(nc_sp),
                            proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")), 'sf')

Comment: It worked perfectly! Why? What was wrong with my computer?

Comment: it missing the proj4string argument, but in mine it would run without it, it defaults to CRS(as.character(NA))

Comment: How would I know if this proj4string argument is causing me for future analysis? would be because of the error `Error in if (!is.na(projargs) &&...`? thx

Comment: just try to pass the argument everytime, you'll have to set crs in some moment, I erased st_set_crs()

Comment: thank you very much for your help!